# getting id of elements inside the div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="maindiv">
    <DIV id="first">first div<DIV>
    <DIV id="second">second div</DIV>
    <input id="input" type="text"/>
    <button id="button" value="send"></button>
</div>
```

I want to get the id of the div inside the main div when one of the inner div is clicked using jquery. How can this be done?

Comment: `id` values cannot contain spaces, so `id="main div"` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#maindiv div').on('click', function(e) { // or '#maindiv > div' for proper children
    e.stopPropagation(); // or else this will bubble up through the DOM
    var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(my_id);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9Bu/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main_div').children().click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Note that "children()" optionally takes a selector, so you could specify which children will have the click event, e.g. the following will make sure that only elements with an id will work:

```
$('#main_div').children('[id]').click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: but if i have the following code how to get the id of each elements when it is clicked                                                                 <div id="main div">
 <DIV id="first">first div<DIV>
 <DIV id="second">second div</DIV>
<input id="input" value="" type="text"></input>
<button id="button" value="go">    </div>

Comment: The code I posted will pop up the id. You could also use "var x = $(this).id;" instead of the alert.

Comment: I'm truly amazed that it worked, considering the code is incorrect. `$(this)` is a jQuery object, which doesn't have an `id` - it will return `undefined`. What you want is `this.id` (references the DOM element directly) or `$(this).attr('id')` (completely unnecessary wrapping in a jQuery object).

Answer (score 0):

```
var the_id;
$("#main_div > div").click( function() {
   the_id = $(this).attr("id);   
}
```

Note that id's can not contain spaces.

Comment: if the elements inside the div are not only divs then what can be done to get the id?i have edited my question please check it.

Comment: $("#main_div").children().click( function() {

Comment: what is it you're trying to do with the id once you've got it?

Comment: i am working on a project in which user can create html interfaces by just dragging and dropping operations i need to delete elements when user selects and click on the delete button